# Tem algum problema ao jogar a função para variável

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alguém sabe me explicar se tem algum problema ao jogar uma função para a variável, por exemplo, nesse caso eu estou falando do `var marcar`.
Nesse código esta funcionando, eu não sei se isso causa uma perca de performance ou outra coisa. O `marcar` só irá ser executado nos momentos que realmente for rodar correto?

```
    $('input:checkbox#marcar').click(function() {
    var valor_id = $(this).data('valor-id'),
        checked  = $(this).is(':checked');

    var marcar = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'marcar.php',
            data: {'valor_id' : valor_id},
            success: function()
            {
                alert('Sucesso!!!');
            }
        });
    }

    if(checked === false)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'verifica.php',
            data: {'valor_id' : valor_id},
            success: function(retorno) {
                var resp = $.parseJSON(retorno);
                if(resp.success === true)
                {
                    var cont = confirm(resp.msg);
                    if(cont === true)
                    {
                        marcar();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this.prop("checked", true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    marcar();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        marcar();
    }

});
```

Comment: Não há problema nenhum, Marcelo.

Answer (score 9):

No Javascript você pode referenciar uma variavel a uma função sem problemas. Porém o comportamento vai ser diferente dependendo dos casos.

**Função nomeada:**

Quando você define uma função nomeada `function nome() {}` ela é colocada em todo o escopo de execução, por exemplo:

```
foo(); // alert('ola')
function foo() { alert('ola'); }
```

**Função anonima:**

Já se você definir em uma variavel ele só vai existir a partir do momento em que a variavel passou a ter atribuição da função (a variavel existe desde o inicio do contexto), exemplo:

```
foo(); // undefined
var foo = function () { alert('ola'); }
foo(); // alert('ola')
```

**Criando referencia de função:**

Ainda é possível importar métodos de outros objetos, mas cuidado!

```
var obj = {
    foo: function () { alert('ola'); }
};
var foo = obj.foo;
foo(); // alert('ola');
obj.foo(); // alert('ola');
```

**Referencia de função que usa contexto:**

Mas se o método tiver dependencia de contexto você pode ter problemas fazendo esse tipo de mixin, por exemplo:

```
var obj = {
    texto: 'ola',
    foo: function () { alert(this.texto); }
};
var foo = obj.foo;
foo(); // alert(undefined);
obj.foo(); // alert('ola');
```

Neste caso quando jogou `obj.foo` em `foo` o contexto mais proximo dela é o objeto `ẁindow` que no caso não tem a propriedade `texto` e por isso ele retorna `undefined`.

```
var obj = {
    texto: 'ola',
    foo: function () { alert(this.texto); }
};
var obj2 = {
    texto: 'tchau'
};
obj2.foo = obj.foo;
obj2.foo(); // alert('tchau');
obj.foo(); // alert('ola');
```

Veja que neste exemplo o `obj2` tem propriedade `texto` diferente do `obj` e a função vai retornar o contexto do objeto onde ela se encontra.

Answer (score 2):

Marcelo, isso é um dos modos de declarar metodos no javascript. Exemplo:

```
var myvar = function() {
  return true;
}
```

Além desse modo, tem esse:

```
function myfunc() {
  return true;
}
```

Bem como desse modo, você pode definir objetos e arrays em váriaveis. Exemplo:

```
var myvar = ['Maçã', 'Morango', 'Uva'];

var myobject = {
  frutas = ['Maçã', 'Morango', 'Uva'],
  carros = ['Gol', 'Uno']
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Tanto não existe problema quanto isso é uma prática muito comum.

No artigo [**Javascript: variável como função e objeto**](http://leobalter.net/desenvolvimento/javascript-variavel-como-funcao-e-objeto/) você pode ver detalhadamente como funciona.